# Using the "!" operator during file input/output operations in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, operators

I'm reviewing a project that does file input/output operations in C++. There are uses for the overloaded `!` operator defined in `std::ios` that I have not encountered before. I know that the `!` operator is used to check if a file has been opened. However, I did not understand why the author used the `fstream` object by using the `!` operator after using the `istream::seekg`, `istream::read`, `ostream::seekp`, `ostream::write` methods in the project I was examining.

Below is a part of the `add()` function in the source code I've reviewed:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

bool add(std::fstream &file, std::istream &input)
{
    file.seekg((id - 1) * sizeof(Person));
    /* What is the purpose of using the "operator!" below? */
    if(!file){ return false; }

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&temp), sizeof(Person));
    /* What is the purpose of using the "operator!" below? */
    if(!file){ return false; }

    file.seekp((id - 1) * sizeof(Person));
    /* What is the purpose of using the "operator!" below? */
    if(!file){ return false; }

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&person), sizeof(Person));
    /* What is the purpose of using the "operator!" below? */
    if(!file){ return false; }
}
```

Do the above uses of the `operator!` operator make any sense?

Comment: `operator!` on a stream checks whether any error bits are set; `!file` is equivalent to `!file.good()`. Failing `open` is one source of error bits, but there are others, e.g. reaching end of file, or attempting to read an integer but encountering characters that can't be interpreted as a number. The code shown is careful to check the success of every file operation.

Comment: `operator!` checks bad and fail bits. Works for more than just not opening a file. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!

Comment: For C++ I/O streams, `operator!()` is overloaded so it returns `true` if the stream is in an error state.   So `if(!file`) tests if `file` is in an error state.   It is equivalent to `if(file.fail())`.    Note:  `std::fstream` is a specialisation of a templated `std::basic_fstream`, and `std::basic_fstream` inherits from a templated class named `std::basic_ios`.  It is `std::basic_ios` which has the member `operator!()` - which is why all stream classes have it.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thanks for your help. The link you shared redirects to a different page. Because '!' character at the end of the link you shared, the link leads to a different page. If you share the link as below, the problem will be solved; [operator!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` operator is overloaded for classes derived from `std::basic_ios` (such as `std::fstream`) to indicate whether or not an error has occurred following an operation, or that has not been cleared after an earlier operation.

[From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!):

> Returns `true` if an error has occurred on the associated stream.
> Specifically, returns `true` if `badbit` or `failbit` is set in `rdstate()`.

In the code sample you have shown, the `!` operator is called after *every* attempted operation on the stream and, if an error *is* detected, the function aborts and returns a `false` signal. (Note that *any* of those seek/read/write operations could potentially fail.)

So:

> *Do the above uses of the operator! operator make any sense?*

Yes, they do. That's good, exemplary code, which should be commended in any review.

Comment: Yes, now I remember; file I/O exhibits the behavior you mentioned as there is a `stream`. But I didn't know that the `!` operator represented this behavior. Thanks.